# MYSQL - MAX() returns wrong date

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have a mysql table like this

```
+----------+----------+-------------------+
| entrykey | user_key |     validfrom      |
+----------+----------+-------------------+
|        1 |        3 | 2016-4-1 0:0:0.0  |
|        2 |        3 | 2016-12-1 0:0:0.0 |
|        3 |        2 | 2016-12-1 0:0:0.0 |
|        4 |        2 | 2016-3-1 0:0:0.0  |
+----------+----------+-------------------+
```

now I am trying to get only the row for each user where the validfrom is the newest. So I am doing a query like this:

```
SELECT entrykey, user_key, max(validfrom)
FROM table
Group by user_key;
```

It is working fine for almost all of my data, just this two examples I posted here in the table select the wrong row which is older. So for user_key 3 it selects entrykey 1 and for the user_key 2 it selects entrykey 4.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no entrykey 2 for user_key  2 in you sample data.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is that you are comparing strings. `Max()` is returning the correct values, for comparison between strings. (`4` is greater than `1`, and `3` is greater than `1`). If you want to compare dates, then you either need the column to contain dates, or you need to convert the strings to dates before comparing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the `validform` should be `2016-03-01` instead of `2016-3-01` because it is not converted into date before compare.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am not able to change the table I am now doing it just like this:
`MAX(STR_TO_DATE(fkem_validfrom, '%Y-%c-%e')) date`

Answer (score 1):

I am totally agree with the point made in the accepted answer (+1 for that). But, even if op somehow convert `validfrom` from string to `DateTime`, his attempt won't give him the desired result.

Let's examine the query given in question:

```
SELECT entrykey, user_key, MAX(STR_TO_DATE(validfrom, '%Y-%c-%e')) as date1
FROM table
Group by user_key;
```

Now, this query will return `user_key` with maximum value of `validfrom` for that particular `user_key`. But the `entrykey` won't be the `entrykey` with max `validfrom`. (Check the first result in demo link)

In order to achieve above task, following query will work just fine!

```
SELECT t1.entrykey, t1.user_key, t2.maxdate as MaxDate
FROM t t1
inner join (select user_key,MAX(STR_TO_DATE(validfrom, '%Y-%c-%e')) as maxdate
            from t
            Group by user_key
            ) t2
on t1.user_key = t2.user_key and t1.validfrom = t2.maxdate;
```

[Click here for Demo with DateTime as datatype of validfrom](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c185d68/4/1)

[Click here for Demo with STR_TO_DATE() function](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83f6ce/5/1)

Hope it helps!

Comment: That is right, I am sorry that I didn't state in the question that I am actually already doing this. I only posted the innerjoin in the question.
Actually I am doing seven joins and to keep it simple I concentrated on the selection of the max value in the answer.
But for other people stumbling across this question, this answer is definitely helpfull.